# Mapping Degree of a Smooth Map from a Compact Manifold without Boundary

Tags: differential-topology

There is a comment in Milnor's "Topology from a Differentiable Viewpoint," that I don't quite understand:

*Let $f$ be a smooth map from $M$ to $N$, where $M$ is compact without boundary, and $N$ is connected, and both manifolds have the same dimension. (We may as well assume also that $N$ is compact without boundary, since otherwise the mod 2 degree would necessarily be zero.)*

So if $N$ is non-compact, then $f$ cannot be surjective, so I see that the mod 2 degree would be zero.

Why does $N$ being compact with boundary would give 0 mod 2 degree? The examples I can think of all have 0 mod 2 degree, but I'm not sure why this is obvious...

Comment: A colleague suggested the following: Suppose that $N$ is a compact manifold with boundary. Then, sew $N$ with itself along the boundary, call it $\hat{N}$. So now $f$ can be thought of as a non-surjective map from $M$ into a compact manifold without boundary $\hat{N}$, so the degree of $f$ is 0 mod 2...

Comment: I realized that this is a rather trivial question: any surjective map onto a manifold with boundary can be deformed by homotopy to a non-surjective map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any surjective map onto a manifold with boundary is homotopic to a non-surjective map, by  "rolling up the sleeves."